# Won't this mysql line call the result?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I've created a database where for example, you already used the code, it adds it into it and the columns are "promocodex" and "idused". When I run my PHP code, it won't return the result I want, nay, I need.

I've tried fetch results, I tried to count the numbers of rows affected but it just doesn't budge. I was thinking I'm using the SELECT function wrong but when I look at it, there's not much wrong about it.

```
<?php
$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {    
    $ckrs=mysql_query("SELECT 'promocodex' FROM `oto_usedpromocodes` WHERE 'idused' ='".$userid."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $recordcode = mysqli_fetch_array($ckrs);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($recordcode) < 0) {
        $msg = "You've already used this promo code!"; 
    }
    else {
        $msg = "It worked!"; 
    } 
}
else {
    $msg = "Something's wrong!"; 
}
?>
```

Form goes like this :

```
"<table width="30%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" border: solid !important; border-radius:5px; background-color:rgb(70, 72, 76); ">
  <tr>
    <td><p>&nbsp;</p><center><font color="red"><strong><?=$clean;?></strong></center></font><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <form action="promocode.php" method="post" name="promocode" id="promocode">
    <table width="500" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:-50px;">
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
      { ?>
        <tr>
          <td  colspan="4" align="center">
            <font color="red"><strong><?=$msg;?></strong></font></td>
        </tr>
    <?
      }    
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" nowrap="nowrap" class="admintd" align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><span><strong>Promo Code<br><br></strong></span></font> </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="formfield" align="center">
                    <input name="promocode" type="text" class="footer-text" value="" width="25" padding="0" />
                </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="footer-text" value="Create" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>"
```

I've been putting a code that's already inside the database, so the result that should come out is "You're already used this promo code!" but what appears is "It worked!"

What I actually want to happen is for the same userid not to be able to use the same code again and again.

Comment: assuming the query is valid (meaning the $userid is NOT empty or invalid) ... try to output the value of: $recordcode

Comment: I tried putting an actual value for $userid, it still outputs the same result..

Comment: @JanCabrera Check the code i have updated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you haven't included the database connection in your call to `mysql_query` and `mysql_error`, which should actually be `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_error`. Change that line to this (assuming your connection is called `$conn`):

```
$ckrs=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT 'promocodex' FROM `oto_usedpromocodes` WHERE 'idused' ='".$userid."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Secondly, you're calling `mysqli_num_rows` on an array (`$recordcode`) instead of on the result set of the query (`$ckrs`). You also comparing for less than 0 where it should be greater than. You need to change this line:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($recordcode) < 0) {
```

to either

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($ckrs) > 0) {
```

or

```
if (!empty($recordcode)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

First this:

```
$ckrs=mysql_query("S ...
```

would work better as:

```
$ckrs=mysqli_query("S ...
```

This is because mysql_* is deprecated.

Next: `mysqli_fetch_array($ckrs);` returns the next row as an array,
so `mysqli_num_rows($recordcode)` might return zero in this case.

Count is usually the way to go in this case, but you might have an error that is being caught.  You can show error with: `mysqli_error($conn)`

Answer (score 1):

Dont use both mysql and mysqli.

mysqli_query($con,$sql). It takes two arguments.

```
$sql = "SELECT promocodex FROM oto_usedpromocodes WHERE idused ='$userid'";
$ckrs = mysqli_query($con,$sql); // where $con is your connection string. 
$recordcode = mysqli_fetch_array($ckrs);
```

Try this it should fine as expected.